# Catch error if $host.ui.PromptForCredential Password is empty and "OK" is selected

Tags: powershell

I am building a program for our maintenance guys at work to give them controlled access to some files we do not want our operators to have access to. The function down below is to capture credentials and I have it set up so if the "X" in the corner is hit or "CANCEL" is they will be re-prompted to enter their credentials. However if they hit "ok" while a username is entered but not a password they don't get re-prompted. How can I make that happen?

```
function Get-Creds {
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
do{
$cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Authenticate to OSD:", "Please enter your Operator Credentials", "", "")
  if(-not $cred){
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Credentials cannot be empty!")
    Get-Creds
    continue
  }

  # ...

  $done = $true
} until ($done)

}
```

Comment: you could use `$cred.Password.Length` to check if the password which was entered is nothing instead of `-not $cred` which always will be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check if the input password was blank, for this you can use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-6.0) to test if the password is null and to decrypt the password of the `PSCredential` Object, you can construct a new instance of [`NetWorkCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential?view=net-6.0) targeting the [`NetworkCredential(String, SecureString)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-net-networkcredential-ctor(system-string-system-security-securestring)) then call the [`.Password`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.password?view=net-6.0#system-net-networkcredential-password) of the instance which returns a *string* (decrypted password).

```
if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace([Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $cred.Password).Password)) {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Password cannot be empty!")
    Get-Creds
    continue
}
```